# Python Removing duplicates ( and not keeping them) in a list

Tags: python

Say I have:

```
x=[a,b,a,b,c,d]
```

I want a way to get

```
y=[c,d]
```

I have managed to do it with count:

```
 for i in x:
   if x.count(i) == 1:
     unique.append(i)
```

The problem is, this is very slow for bigger lists, help?

Comment: Do you want to preserve the order of the characters?

Comment: no, just want the value thank you

Comment: Create a `collections.Counter` dict and then loop over list again remove items with count > 1.

Comment: the pandas way would be `import pandas as pd
x=['a','b','a','b','c','d']
s = pd.Series(x)
s[s.isin(s.unique()[(s.value_counts()==1).values])]` but there would be a cost in the construction of the Series from the list in the first place

Comment: @Reticality that dup you linked to is not really an optimal answer for this question

Answer (score 4):

First use a dict to count:

```
d = {}
for i in x:
    if i not in d:
        d[i] = 0
    d[i] += 1
y = [i for i, j in d.iteritems() if j == 1]
```

Answer (score 3):

```
x=["a","b","a","b","c","d"]

from collections import Counter

print([k for k,v in Counter(x).items() if v == 1])    
['c', 'd']
```

Or to guarantee the order create the Counter dict first then iterate over the x list doing lookups for the values only keeping k's that have a value of 1:

```
x = ["a","b","a","b","c","d"]
from collections import Counter

cn = Counter(x)
print([k for k in x if cn[k] == 1])
```

So one pass over x to create the dict and another pass in the comprehension giving you an overall `0(n)` solution as opposed to your quadratic approach using count.

The Counter dict counts the occurrences of each element:

```
In [1]: x = ["a","b","a","b","c","d"]    
In [2]: from collections import Counter    
In [3]: cn = Counter(x)    
In [4]: cn
Out[4]: Counter({'b': 2, 'a': 2, 'c': 1, 'd': 1})
In [5]: cn["a"]
Out[5]: 2  
In [6]: cn["b"]
Out[6]: 2    
In [7]: cn["c"]
Out[7]: 1
```

Doing  `cn[k]` returns the count for each element so we only end up keeping c and d.

Answer (score -2):

The best way to do this is my using the `set()` function like this:

```
x=['a','b','a','b','c','d']
print list(set(x))
```

As the `set()` function returns an unordered result. Using the `sorted()` function, this problem can be solved like so:

```
x=['a','b','a','b','c','d']
print list(sorted(set(x)))
```

Comment: This doesn't satisfy the OP's request to filter elements that have a count > 1